# Query - Content type

Tags: database, 8, entities

I want to get all created content of some content type by query. By now I can access nodes by their ID.

`$MyNode = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1)`

I tried some query, but none of them worked for me. Maybe wrong conditions. My content type is 'beacons'.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
```

Cant find it in my d8 book too.

Comment: Since you tried some queries, and they didn't work for you, may you show them? Differently, you would be going to get a very minimal answer basing on the few details you told us.

Comment: You should update your question, it will make it clearer to everyone else arriving at this post to figure out what the problem is. @kiamlaluno is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should suffice:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'beacons');
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

Here is a drush one-liner to test this on my D8 instance, where I have one article node:

```
 drush ev "var_dump(\\Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','article')->execute());"
```

Gives me:

```
array(1) {
  [101]=>
  string(3) "101"
}
```

where 101 is the nid of the article node.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answer! If i want 'articles' it would be: $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'articles');?

Comment: It would be $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'article');    Don't use plural, the machine name is in singular, at least for 'article' and 'page'.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Cause i am getting null even in 'article'. Or maybe i am tring to access content in bad way. I am trying $entity_ids[0]

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I updated the answer with some test code and output. Have a look at your code for some typo.

Comment: Thank you..looks like it work for me too! I tried count($entity_ids) and gives me number of articles i have. I am just new to symfony2 so i have problem accesing fields of my contents. But finaly working example :)

Comment: Great! See you around @RadoInko!